# Pattern Match Vector Value in Data.Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I am using Data.Aeson to parse JSON to my custom type. 
I try to pattern match `Vector Value` (`Array`) in my `FromJSON` instance, but don't know how I can do it. JSON `value` key can have a value of a `String`, a list of `String` or a list of list of `String`.

```
instance FromJSON Foo where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    case lookup "value" o of
      Just (String s) -> pure $ SimpleText s
      Just foo@(Array (String s)) -> pure $ ListOfText $ V.toList <$> V.mapM (parseJSON :: Value -> Parser Text) foo
      Just foo@(Array (Array (String s))) -> pure $ ListOfListOfText $ V.toList <$> V.mapM (parseJSON :: Value -> Parser Text) $ V.toList <$> V.mapM (parseJSON :: Value -> [Parser Value]) foo
```

with

```
data Foo = SimpleText Text
         | ListOfText [Text]
         | ListOfListOfText [[Text]]
         deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

Can I use pattern matching on Array to handle this case? or should I manually check the type of every `Value`? and how do to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot pattern match the way you are trying to do here. A JSON Array can contain values of different types, and you cannot pattern match on all values in a list like they where one.

There are several ways to solve your actual problem here. There is a **easy way**, and there is an **explicit way** that will give you better error messages.

#### Easy way

The easy way is to use the fact that there already exist `FromJSON` instances for `Text` and `[a]`. Because of this you can use the `Alternative` operator to write your instance like this:

```
instance FromJSON Foo where
    parseJSON v =  (SimpleText <$> parseJSON v) 
               <|> (ListOfText <$> parseJSON v) 
               <|> (ListOfListOfText <$> parseJSON v)
```

The trick here is that Aeson first will try to parse a `Text` value, then if it fails it will try a `[Text]`, if it fails again it will try `[[Text]]`.

The problem with this solution is that if your JSON is malformed the error messages might not make sense. For example if you give it a top level Null value your error will be that it expects a `[[Text]]`, since you will always get the error for the last value in the chain.

#### Explicit way

To get better error messages you have to be more expicit about what values you expect. What if the result is an empty array, should it be a `ListOfText` or a `ListOfListOfText`? Since we cant pattern match on a `Vector` directly, we can turn it into a list and pattern match on it:

```
instance FromJSON Foo where
    parseJSON v = case v of
        -- If its a string, we return the string as a SimpleText
        (String s) -> return $ SimpleText s

        -- If its an array, we turn the vector to a list so we can pattern match on it
        (Array a)  -> case V.toList a of

            -- If its a empty list, we return a empty ListOfText
            []             -> return $ ListOfText []

            -- If the first value is a string, we put it as the first element of our ListOfTexts and try to parse the rest.
            (String s: xs) -> ListOfText . (s:) <$> mapM parseJSON xs

            -- If the first value is an array, we try to parse it as [Text], then parse the rest.
            (Array a: xa)  -> ListOfListOfText <$> ((:) <$> parseJSON (Array a) <*> mapM parseJSON xa)

            -- If the first value is neither a string or array we return a error message.
            _              -> fail "Expected an Array or an Array of Arrays."

        -- If the top level value is not a string or array we return a error message.
        _ -> fail "Expected a String or Array"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution I found was really close from your second way. But I didn't handle the empty array case. Good catch.